# in os x, typing ctrl-a in python console gets ^a, not going to the head of line

Tags: python, macos, input

ctrl-a is supposed to make the cursor go to the head of line, but instead i get ^a typed in.
after i type shift + <- to delete the ^a, ctrl-a works properly, but TAB failed to do auto completion.

any one have idea what is going wrong?

my OS X is 10.9.4. thanks ahead

Comment: How did you invoke the python console, in this case?

Comment: hi, Jade, I invoke python using iterm2, typing python in the iterm2 console

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe try some other terminal see if it behaves differently.